# Unable to add cell to UICollectionView using Interface Builder

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, interface-builder, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling,i can't add a UICollectionViewCell to my class.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago, I fixed it by dragging from the outlets tab in the inspector view (from the "+" sign)

Answer (score 0):

After adding a Button to the cell , I was able to add a reference to the button in the cell.
My conception to add reference to an empty cell was wrong.